# Tab content of JavaFX TabPane remains appearing in other tab (when inside a Dialog)

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX standalone application with Java 8 (1.8.0_60) and I'm facing an issue with the TabPane (without success yet googling a lot).

I have a view (a FXML form made using JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0) that have a TabPane with two Tabs. I open this form as a dialog (that has it's own controller) in order to "popup" the form without exiting the main form. The problem is that some components in the "tab 1" are appearing in "tab 2" when I switch them. As I have a lot of other tabs in my application (no one in a dialog) and never faced this problem, so that I guess that it's related with the fact that I'm using a TabPane inside a dialog.

[A print of the issue, notice that "Label of Tab 1" is from Tab 1 but is appearing in Tab 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze0V9.png)

Following are some excerpts to give more context of the problem:

1. The dialog controller (lets call it DialogController):

   ```
   private FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
   private Stage dialogStage;

   public DialogController() {
       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resourcePath));
       fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
       fxmlLoader.setController(this);
       fxmlLoader.load();

       Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
       dialogStage.setTitle(stageTitle);
       dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
       dialogStage.initOwner(getMainApplicationStage());
       dialogStage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader.load()));
   }
   ```
2. The main controller:

   ```
   DialogController priceController = new DialogController();
   dialogController.getDialogStage().showAndWait();
   ```
3. The FXML file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
   <?import java.lang.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
   <?import java.lang.*?>
   <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

   <fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
      <children>
         <TabPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
           <tabs>
             <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
               <content>
                 <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                        <children>
                           <Label layoutX="24.0" layoutY="23.0" text="Label of Tab1" />
                        </children>
                     </AnchorPane>
               </content>
             </Tab>
             <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
               <content>
                 <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                        <children>
                           <Label layoutX="38.0" layoutY="62.0" text="Label of Tab 2" />
                        </children>
                     </AnchorPane>
               </content>
             </Tab>
           </tabs>
         </TabPane>
      </children>
   </fx:root>
   ```

Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something opening my form in a dialog?

Comment: Why are you calling `fxmlLoader.load()` twice? I'm not sure this is the cause of your problem, but it surely can't be a good thing to do.

Comment: @sillyfly This is precisely the cause of the problem. The Objectgraph gets contructed twice and layed over the same root (anchor pane).

Comment: @Bruno N Please provide fully runnable and minimal examples of your problem in the future. That increases the chances of an useful answer dramatically.

Comment: @sillyfly In my application the two blocks of code are in a tow separated methods (I put them here in the constructor just to summarize the problem, but the essence is the same). When I load the views in the main form I just call the first method, but when I load them in a Dialog I call the first followed by the second, this is why I'm calling `fxmlLoader.load()` twice. And you're absolutely right: That's not a good thing to do! I fixed this and the problem was solved!!! Thank you a lot for your time and inputs!

Comment: @OJKrylow You do are right: Calling `fxmlLoader.load()` is precisely the cause of the problem! I did this just by mistake and now its working perfectly! Thank you too for your time and inputs. I'll take into account what you said about provide fully runnable and minimal examples in the next times. Thank you again!